# Embedded Youtube video - Difference between UIWebView and Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube

Why there is a visual difference between Safari and UIWebView for the same Youtube URL?

```
// UIWebView
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/NhPqn7MuDy0"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];

// Safari
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/NhPqn7MuDy0"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

[image: Safari]
[image: UIWebView]

Answer (score 1):

Nitro Java script engine is NOT supported for UIWebView.Formatting of webpage and rendering of javascript elements causes difference in displaying same content on UIWebView and Safari(Native Browser).

Sorry, if am NOT correct.